# Were there ever DnD3.X rules for leprechauns?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, races, dnd-3e

Were there ever DnD3.X rules for leprechauns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in Necromancer Games' Tome of Horrors, p.256, [available in PDF on RPGNow](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=3019).  It's probably the most respected third party monster book; in fact it is still cited frequently by Paizo in Pathfinder products.

There's also a house-rule one [on the D&D Wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Leprechauns_%28DnD_Race%29).